# System verilog throughout usage

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to code the following:

let's say that X is a bool term, and Y is a sequence, I would like to have a property saying that `(X throughout Y) |-> term_to_check`

meaning: if you see that term X holds for the entire Y sequence, then **at the end of the sequence** check some term. the problem is I'm not sure whether the above writing will check the term at the end of the sequence or during it.

any ideas how to code the described behavior?

Answer (score 1):

By using the *overlapping* implication operator `|->`, the `term_to_check` is checked in the *same clock cycle* that sequence `Y` ends. If you want it to check in the cycle *following* the end of the sequence, you could use the *non-overlapping* implication `|=>`, but my preference is always using the overlapping operator with `|-> ##1`.

Comment: I want it to be checked in the cycle of the end of the sequence, I am simply not sure that the above writing is doing that. 
I want the checking to be performed every cycle in which the sequence on the left of |-> triggers..

Comment: That should be working. You need to post a complete example if it is not doing what you expect it to do.